How can I display prices for all product variants?
I'm selling products with variants based on 'size' and 'Quantity' attributes, each with a unique price. I want to display the price of each variant ( on product page) within its respective label (or in a new span element next to it), regardless of whether it's selected or not. Can you provide the specific code snippets required to implement this?
I would appreciate any help...
**Note: Dawn theme **
My current Structure

The structure I want is shown below. Similar to the example, when selecting options, the variant prices should update in their box or in a new span tag nearby. With a small CSS adjustment, it should be easy to hide the initial prices for the 'Size' variants.

Since there is a dynamic relationship between the 'Size' and 'Quantity' variants, prices should update whenever these options are selected.
I tried the code below, but I just couldn’t achieve the result I wanted!
"main-product","price", "product-variant-picker" liquid
product-variant-picker.liquid (Below)
{% comment %}
  Renders product variant-picker

  Accepts:
  - product: {Object} product object.
  - block: {Object} passing the block information.
  - product_form_id: {String} Id of the product form to which the variant picker is associated.
  Usage:
  {% render 'product-variant-picker', product: product, block: block, product_form_id: product_form_id %}
{% endcomment %}
{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <variant-selects
    id="variant-selects-{{ section.id }}"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
  >
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      {%- liquid
        assign swatch_count = option.values | map: 'swatch' | compact | size
        assign picker_type = block.settings.picker_type

        if swatch_count > 0 and block.settings.swatch_shape != 'none'
          if block.settings.picker_type == 'dropdown'
            assign picker_type = 'swatch_dropdown'
          else
            assign picker_type = 'swatch'
          endif
        endif
      -%}
      {%- if picker_type == 'swatch' -%}
        <fieldset class="js product-form__input product-form__input--swatch">
          <legend class="form__label">
            {{ option.name }}:
            <span data-selected-value>
              {{- option.selected_value -}}
            </span>
          </legend>
          {% render 'product-variant-options',
            product: product,
            option: option,
            block: block,
            picker_type: picker_type
          %}
        </fieldset>
      {%- elsif picker_type == 'button' -%}
        <fieldset class="js product-form__input product-form__input--pill">
          <legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}</legend>
          {% render 'product-variant-options',
            product: product,
            option: option,
            block: block,
            picker_type: picker_type
          %}
        </fieldset>
      {%- else -%}
        <div class="product-form__input product-form__input--dropdown">
          <label class="form__label" for="Option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
            {{ option.name }}
          </label>
          <div class="select">
            {%- if picker_type == 'swatch_dropdown' -%}
              <span
                data-selected-value
                class="dropdown-swatch"
              >
                {% render 'swatch', swatch: option.selected_value.swatch, shape: block.settings.swatch_shape %}
              </span>
            {%- endif -%}
            <select
              id="Option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
              class="select__select"
              name="options[{{ option.name | escape }}]"
              form="{{ product_form_id }}"
            >
              {% render 'product-variant-options',
                product: product,
                option: option,
                block: block,
                picker_type: picker_type
              %}
            </select>
            <span class="svg-wrapper">
              {{- 'icon-caret.svg' | inline_asset_content -}}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}

    <script type="application/json" data-selected-variant>
      {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant | json }}
    </script>
  </variant-selects>
{%- endunless -%}


You can display price of each variant with this code:
{% for variant in product.variants %}
   {% if variant.option1 == value %}
        {{ variant.price | money }}
   {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}

Full code:
FILE : snippets/product-variant-options.liquid
{% comment %}
  Renders product variant options

  Accepts:
  - product: {Object} product object.
  - option: {Object} current product_option object.
  - block: {Object} block object.


  Usage:
  {% render 'product-variant-options',
    product: product,
    option: option,
    block: block
  %}
{% endcomment %}
{%- liquid
  assign variants_available_arr = product.variants | map: 'available'
  assign variants_option1_arr = product.variants | map: 'option1'
  assign variants_option2_arr = product.variants | map: 'option2'
  assign variants_option3_arr = product.variants | map: 'option3'

  assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id
-%}

{%- for value in option.values -%}
  {%- liquid
    assign option_disabled = true

    for option1_name in variants_option1_arr
      case option.position
        when 1
          if variants_option1_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 2
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 3
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option2 and variants_option3_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
      endcase
    endfor
  -%}

  {%- if block.settings.picker_type == 'button' -%}
    <input
      type="radio"
      id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
      name="{{ option.name }}"
      value="{{ value | escape }}"
      form="{{ product_form_id }}"
      {% if option.selected_value == value %}
        checked
      {% endif %}
      {% if option_disabled %}
        class="disabled"
      {% endif %}
    >
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      {% if variant.option1 == value %}
        {{ variant.price | money }}
      {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}
    <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
      {{ value -}}
      <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.variant_sold_out_or_unavailable' | t }}</span>
    </label>
  {%- elsif block.settings.picker_type == 'dropdown' -%}
    <option
      value="{{ value | escape }}"
      {% if option.selected_value == value %}
        selected="selected"
      {% endif %}
    >
      {% if option_disabled -%}
        {{- 'products.product.value_unavailable' | t: option_value: value -}}
      {%- else -%}
        {{- value -}}
      {%- endif %}
    </option>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}

